# Triggered Send sending 2 emails every time

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am having this strange problem. Have a Triggered Send set up from Lead object in Salesforce.

Whenever I modify a lead record (to meet the Triggered Send criteria), it queues up 2 emails in Marketing Cloud.

What could be causing this? Below is the screenshot of my Triggered Send in Salesforce -

[image]

Comment: Add your trigger code please. I am not sure we can help without seeing it.

Comment: added the screenshot

Comment: Do you have any other triggers on Lead? What could possibly happening is that you have something on Lead that is updating it after you update the record, which will cause the triggered send to send twice (once for each edit)

Comment: I have 4 Process Builders written on Lead object .. Can that be a problem?

Answer (score -1):

Check Workflow, Process Builder, or Apex Triggers and see if the record is being updated to not meet and then updated to meet the criteria.

That would be the best route to find the root cause.

Comment: This is not related to any apex trigger .. It is exacttarget triggered send

Comment: @ManeeshGupta Just trying to help here partner. Think about this at the most basic level - the "Trigger Send When" critieria.